# PugiXML error - status_end_element_mismatch

Tags: android, c++, xml, java-native-interface, pugixml

I am using pugiXML in one of my examples(Android with JNI) and I am trying to parse an XML file that is written is Chinese or Japanese for example and I always get

- **case status_end_element_mismatch**: return "Start-end tags mismatch"; almost always on some random line near or at the end of a XML file.
- I get the parse result with

`pugi::xml_document doc;
pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load(File._Buffer);
 if (result){
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyExample", "XML [ %s ] ;parsed without errors, attr value:[ %s ] ",File._Buffer , doc.child("node").attribute("attr").value());
 else {
      __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyExample", "Error description: %s" , result.description());
      __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyExample", "Error offset: %ul" , result.offset);
 }`

My English language XML works just fine.

I have checked the XML file with various validators and even "by hand - line by line" and it is not missing any tags and all validators confirm that it is a valid XML file.

My file is not any bigger than 1 mg. I have read that people used with success pugiXML with over 9 mg files so it can`t be a memory issue.

Did anyone had this kind of problems? If somebody have some pointers?

Thank you.

Comment: Is File._Buffer a null-terminated string?

Comment: No, it prints data until some point in the file and stops at one of the ">" element. This print also:  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyExample", "XML [  ] parsed with errors, attr value: [ %s" ,doc.child("node").attribute("attr").value());

Comment: I'm not sure I got that... Can you post the code that creates and fills File._Buffer?

Comment: It can't all fit in one comment so i'l break it down. I create the file with android asset manager: `sourceFile* sourceAndroid::open(const char *lpszFileName) {

 AAsset* assetF;
 try{
  assetF = AAssetManager_open(_AssetAndroid, lpszFileName, AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
 }
 catch (int e){
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyExample", "open catch");
 }
 sourceFileAndroid* file = 0;
 if (assetF) {
  file = new sourceFileAndroid();
  file->init(assetF);
 }

 return file;
}`

Comment: Then I fill the _Buffer in this function: `bool ResourceFile::open(const char* FileName)
{  
 sourceFile F; 
 if (F.open(FileName)) {  
  _Size = 0;
        
  ResourceStat Stat;
  if (Resource::stat(FileName, &Stat)) {
   _Size = Stat.nSize;
  }
        
  _Buffer = new char[_Size + 1];
  F.read(_Buffer, _Size);
  _Buffer[_Size] = 0;
        
  F.close();
        
  
        
  return true;
 } 
     
 return false;
}
`

Comment: I have checked the File._Buffer and it is not null, it contains the data from XML file.

Comment: What would this: ```__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyExample", "XML [ %s ]",File._Buffer);``` print?

Comment: So far it looks like either your XML is simply incorrect - e.g. closing node does not match opening node - *or* there's an internal NUL character somewhere in your XML data (which also makes it malformed)

Comment: So yeah, it would help if you uploaded a hex dump (xxd file.xml) of your file somewhere, and the offset at which parsing fails.

Comment: I have checked the XML file with 3 different validators and by "hand", 1000% no missing tags. I don't have an idea how to get hex dump on my file. My error offset is: 3410061 and log writes that "error at [ > ] ". I tried an implementation on PC with pugi, same XML file and it works. Maybe it is some kind of Android limitation because Chinese doesn`t use the same ASCII code as English?

Comment: pugixml is agnostic to the system charset so it should not really matter. What's File._Size? Also, can you post the data around the error offset - e.g. ```for (unsigned int i = offset - 10; i < File._Size; ++i) { __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyExample", "XML [%d] = %d", i, File._Buffer[i]); }``` ?

Comment: error offset =  3410061 , File size: 341007, I will attach the print you wrote in a minute.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By1-bVmUADv5NzdyczlzZ3diTWc/view?usp=sharing I have attached the log here. I am confused, this log prints the place where parsing fails?

Comment: I have removed indendations from the XML file and the log is now like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By1-bVmUADv5aXFuejE3dGphU1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't quite understand what's happening. The log indeed is supposed to print where parsing fails. However, it's very weird that parsing fails at the same offset *and* file size is the same *but* you're saying you actually removed indentation in the second log? How can the file size stay the same after you remove indentation from it?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a bug in implementation of ResourceStat so you're actually trying to parse a truncated file? That would explain the errors and why you're getting the size that's the same. Is the size of the file on PC also 341007 bytes?

Comment: I have consulted with a friend too and he said the same thing. I`l investigate this and ASAP will post the answer if I reach one :).

Comment: Yes, on PC the file size is 356874. Looks like the problem is in opening the file?

Comment: Yeah, probably either in opening the file or in getting the file size.

Answer (score 0):

After careful analysis the problem was in the information while opening the file. Since I was reading multiple XML files I simply read the WRONG file`s size which was smaller than the original file I was trying to read.

The pugiXML read the file with a size from another(smaller) file and while reading it, the file was truncated and the end parent tag simply did`t close the line - therefore Pugixml reported the error  "Start-end tags mismatch".

When given the right size, the xml parsing works excellent. I want to thank Zeuxcg for huge help on this matter! Thank you for helping me.